# What is the correct way add a protocol to the macOS info.plist using electron-builder?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, info.plist

I need to be able to launch my Electron app from the the browser (like sign in to Slack does). I know that I can add my protocol name to my Electron app using [app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(protocol[, path, args])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args) in Electron.

Then in [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac), I can use the package.json config `build.mac` with the `extendInfo` property to define "The extra entries for Info.plist". This however is the only instructions the docs give on how to use it.

What is the correct way add a protocol to the macOS info.plist using electron and electron-builder config `build.mac.extendInfo` and be able to use it as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

It now works with the following - I have added this to my Electron package.json:

```json
        "protocols": {
            "name": "my-app",
            "schemes": [
                "my-app"
            ]
        },
        "mac": {
            "target": "dmg",
            "extendInfo": "my-app"
        },
```

I have this in the electron.js:

```js
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('my-app');
```

And this in my React browser client app code to launch the application from the browser:

```js
document.location = 'my-app://open?url='
```

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to how custom schemes are used to receive OAuth responses, as in my code sample which you can run locally, then use deep linking etc:

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)

Points of interest:

- An interstitial web page returns control to the browser app - see [this page](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/web/postlogin.html)
- My [package.json](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/package.json#L19) exposes the scheme for Electron deployment

This should give you something to compare against. Here is the key code:

### INTERSTITIAL WEB PAGE INVOKING APP

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var redirectUri = 'x-mycompany-desktopapp:/callback';
    if (window.location.search) {
        redirectUri += window.location.search;
    }

    document.getElementById('continueButton').onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = redirectUri;
    };
}
```

### REGISTERING THE SCHEME

This gets picked up by Electron packager and included in platform specific binaries, resulting in OS specific registration:

```json
"build": {
    "protocols": {
      "name": "finaldesktopapp",
      "schemes": [
        "x-mycompany-desktopapp"
      ]
    }
  },
```

### RECEIVING NOTIFICATIONS

This enables the following code to work in the main side of the app, as specified in the `main.ts` file:

```js
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(this._configuration.oauth.privateSchemeName);
```

Finally you register a callback that can parse the URL and take whatever is the appropriate action - completing a login in my case.

```js
private _receiveNotificationInRunningInstance(privateSchemeUrl: string) {
}
```

The mechanics are a little tricky and the notification is received differently on macOS to Windows / Linux. See [this source file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/main.ts#L183) and its comments which explain the details.

Comment: Hi @Gary Archer, thanks very much for this answer, I'll come back here once I've had time to dig in to all the links you've provided!

Comment: This looks very helpful, but it is entirely a "link only answer". Could you bring some of the content into it, so that any link breakage does not affect it?

Comment: Thanks for the edits Gary - very helpful. (Minor feedback - there is a heading style you can use in Markdown that give semantic/structural information to search engines and screen-readers: use `---` under the heading text).

Comment: Thanks halfer - feedback always welcome ...